# SyncFusion Dashboard and Google Bigquery is possible?

Tags: google-bigquery, dashboard, syncfusion

Now I got involved in a project that´s required to make queries quickly, and we have the access to Google tools Bigquery and the Syncfusion Dashboard. Our objective is to try to connect both platforms (the first to make queries, and second to show Dashboard towards our customers. Anyone know how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Syncfusion Dashboard Designer has support to connect the Google's BigQuery and prepare the dashboard, and it can be shown to end user either through Syncfusion Dashboard Server or Dashboard Platform SDK.

Read the Syncfusion Community forum link for more detail. https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/138672/a-connection-between-syncfusion-dashboard-and-google-bigquery-is-possible